# How to find the rank of a sudoku without row reduction?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, sudoku

Furthermore, is a sudoku always of full rank? When is it full rank and when is it not? I realized these questions are quite out there and there may not be any meaningful answer to this.

Comment: It is definitely possible for a $4\times4$ "sudoku" to either have full rank or not. For example, $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)$ has rank 3, while $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 4 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)$ has rank 4. I would assume the same is likely true of actual $9\times9$ sudoku matrices...

Comment: I suspect a sudoku is of full rank iff it has a unique solution.

Comment: @Moriarty: A filled $9\times9$ matrix according to the sudoku rules and without empty cells is a unique solution. I looked at [this example](http://sandwalk.blogspot.de/2007/06/i-knew-it-there-can-be-more-than-one.html) and found both alternative solutions to have rank $9$.

Comment: @AxelKemper how did come upon the proof in your first sentence?

Comment: A [sudoku puzzle](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Mahmood/More.html) is a partially filled grid or board. `Unique solution` means that there is only one way to fill the empty cells and reach the solution as completely filled grid. As the rank can only be computed for a complete grid matrix, a grid without empty cells represents a unique solution. The link in my comment above shows a solution which can be transformed into another solution by swapping four cells. But I still would call each of these solutions `unique`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) constraint solver and [Chuffed](https://github.com/chuffed/chuffed) as solver back-end, I found the following rank $8$ sudoku:

```
9 1 6  2 7 4  5 3 8
2 7 5  8 6 3  4 9 1
8 4 3  5 1 9  6 2 7

6 2 9  1 3 7  8 5 4
4 5 1  6 2 8  9 7 3
7 3 8  4 9 5  2 1 6

3 8 7  9 5 6  1 4 2
1 9 4  7 8 2  3 6 5
5 6 2  3 4 1  7 8 9
```

Another [rank 8](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rank%20%7B%7B3,2,1,7,5,6,8,9,4%7D,%7B4,7,9,2,1,8,3,5,6%7D,%7B8,6,5,9,4,3,2,1,7%7D,%7B5,3,2,1,6,9,4,7,8%7D,%7B1,9,8,3,7,4,5,6,2%7D,%7B7,4,6,8,2,5,1,3,9%7D,%7B2,5,4,6,9,1,7,8,3%7D,%7B9,1,3,4,8,7,6,2,5%7D,%7B6,8,7,5,3,2,9,4,1%7D%7D) solution found using the MiniZinc `G12 lazyfd` solver back-end:

```
3 2 1  7 5 6  8 9 4
4 7 9  2 1 8  3 5 6
8 6 5  9 4 3  2 1 7

5 3 2  1 6 9  4 7 8
1 9 8  3 7 4  5 6 2
7 4 6  8 2 5  1 3 9

2 5 4  6 9 1  7 8 3
9 1 3  4 8 7  6 2 5
6 8 7  5 3 2  9 4 1
```

My model (based on [this example](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/blob/master/tests/examples/sudoku.mzn)):

```
int: s = 3;
int: n = s*s;
set of int: S = 1..s;
set of int: N = 1..n;

%  sudoku board is a n x n = s² x s² matrix:
array[N, N] of var N: puzzle;

%  column multipliers for full-rank determination
%  extra small range chosen to speed-up search
int: CMDIM = 1;
array[N] of var -CMDIM .. CMDIM: colMults;

include "alldifferent.mzn";

% All cells in a row, in a column, and in a subsquare are different.
constraint
    forall(i in N)( alldifferent(j in N)( puzzle[i,j] ))
    /\
    forall(j in N)( alldifferent(i in N)( puzzle[i,j] ))
    /\
    forall(i, j in S)
        ( alldifferent(p,q in S)( puzzle[s*(i-1)+p, s*(j-1)+q] ));

%  additional constraint to enforce non-full rank for puzzle matrix
%  Iff a linear combination of columns sums up to the null column,
%  we don't have full rank  
constraint forall(j in N) (
    0 = sum([colMults[i] * puzzle[j, i] | i in N])
  );  

%  exclude trivial solution with all-zero mutipliers
constraint exists([colMults[i] != 0 | i in N]);

solve satisfy;

function string: it(bool: cond, string: yes_s) =
  if cond then yes_s else "" endif;

function string: ite(bool: cond, string: yes_s, string :no_s) =
  if cond then yes_s else no_s endif;

output [ "sudoku:\n" ] ++
    [ show(puzzle[i,j]) ++
        if j = n then
            ite(i mod s = 0 /\ i < n, "\n\n", "\n")
        else
            ite(j mod s = 0, "  ", " ")
        endif
    | i,j in N ] ++
    ["\n rank {"] ++
    [ it(j = 1, "{") ++
      show(puzzle[i,j]) ++ 
      it(j < n, ",") ++
      it(j == n, "}") ++
      it((j == n) /\ (i < n), ",")
    | i,j in N ] ++
    ["}"] ++
    ["\nColumn Multipliers: "] ++
    [show(colMults[i]) ++ " " | i in N];
```

Comment: What's the highest or lowest rank you e found?

Comment: No rank below 8 yet. Most 9x9 sudokus certainly have full rank 9.